# setting background transparent in scrollbar does not show text undearneath it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to implement a transparent scrollbar over the texts of children. So using transparent background only allow the background of children but not the texts.

sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kujcdv?file=index.html

I have also used background-clip as text but no use. In the above sample some text go under the scrollbar not visible despite of settings scrollbar track/thumb to transparent.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want scrollbar or scrollbar track to be transparent?

Comment: Scroll track to be transparent that i should be able to see those text underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this style for p tag - background: rgba(0, 151, 19, 0.3);
0.3 is the opacity for background color. It range 0.1 to 1

Comment: It's not working. The end letters for first four lines are still not visible

Comment: Add style for P tag in style.css
padding: 2px 12px 2px 2px;

Comment: what you just suggested is exactly opposite of what i wanted. I want to have a scrollbar above those actual texts